# Netty IdleStateHandler per channel

Tags: netty

Hi I've a trouble with the IdleStateHandler when it's added to a pipeline.
when I add using the

```
m_channel.pipeline().addFirst("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 30));
```

I say every channel to fire an IdleState event if there isn't any activity (read or write) on that channel in a period of 30 secs. But this setting is for every channel handled by the pipeline where the IdleStateHandler was defined. 
 The question is how can I set a different idle time for each single channel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question... Each ChannelPipeline is assigned to exactly one Channel so it should work as aspected. If it not does open an issue at the netty bugtracker

Comment: I thought that the pipeline is a single instance shared across overall channels, instead correct me if I'm wrong, with the DSL i define a pipeline that is cloned for every channel, so every channel has got it's own distinct pipeline. So now sounds ok.

Comment: Each Channel has its own ChannelPipeline.

Answer (score 0):

The ChannelPipeline is channel specific, you can custom your channel IdleStateHandler, but you also need to provide a Timer before you initialize the IdleStateHandler.